# Uniform circular motion attached to a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, spring

I'm having trouble wihh this problem I got in an exam and I got it wrong.
In the problem is you have a frictionless table and a nail in the centre where a spring is attached. At the end of the spring there is a mass attached to it. The problem doesn't have numbers, $K$ is the springs constant, $L$ is its natural length, $m$ is the mass of the object attached.

**The question is**: where is the position of the mass so that the movement is a uniform circular motion?

I feel like this problem is very vague. I have trouble understanding and imagining how can such movement occur. So far i have this:

\begin{equation}
  K(L-r)=mv^2/r
\end{equation}

I'm almost sure this can't be the solution because I never specify the uniformity of the motion, but I don't know how to either. Still, if I consider that the elastic force only acts in the $r$ axes, it's like I'm saying it's uniform, right? Because there's no other force component that can change velocity's magnitude...

Still I'm almost sure I got it wrong because it seems too simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything kept on a table with a spring attached to it does not start to move on its own. So you have to give it an initial push perpendicular to the radius vector. That would **elongate** the spring and the spring will try to pull it back with a force. Hence the actual length of the spring would be $(r+x)$ and not $(r-x)$ as you have stated.

Also, there should be no tangential force because you state that the motion is uniform, hence its speed should not change.

And I think that the expression would be

> $Kx=\frac{mv^2}{r+x}$

Where r is the length of the spring and x is the extension in the spring.

You see, if $x$ remains constant, the centripetal force will be constant and you can imagine the spring to be a string, as in string the tension remains constant for uniform circular motion and it happens in real life and thus is not vague. So similar stuff can also happen with springs!

( I hope you wont get this wrong next time in your exam :-P )

Answer (score 2):

To have a perfectly circular motion, the mass needs to be at an equilibrium position such that the centripetal force is equal to the spring force.

Using Hooke's law, if $x$ is the spring's elongation from equilibrium, then,
the spring's force is $-Kx$.

Using centripetal equations of motions, the centripetal force is
$\frac{mv^2}{r}=m\omega^2r$ where $\omega$ is the rotational speed.
Here, $r=L+x$ for a stretched spring. Applying Newton's law we get:

$Kx = m\omega^2(L+x)$ and then,

$$x = \frac{m\omega^2L}{K-m\omega^2}$$

So, if the mass stands at $L+x$, the motion is perfectly circular.

Comment: The spring force is the force causing the centripetal acceleration and it is not an equilibrium situation because the mass is accelerating.

Comment: Indeed the mass is not in static equilibrium, but what I meant was in equilibrium in the radial direction.

Answer (score 0):

The spring needs to apply a constant inward radial force on the mass.
To do that the spring must be stretched to a length $L+x$ and not be compressed to a length $L-x$.

The inward radial force on the mass due to the spring, $Kx$, produces the centripetal acceleration of the mass, $m(L+x) \omega ^2$, and Newton,s second law $F=ma$ connects the two quantities.